# Let $L,F$ be extensions over the field $K$ and $L,F$ are contained in a common field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L,F$ be extensions over the field $K$ and $L,F$ are contained in a common field. Prove that if $L=K(S)$, with $S$ is a nonempty subset of $L$ then $LF=F(S)$.

Thank for any insight.

Comment: They are both the smallest field containing $L$ and $F$ correct?

Comment: But why if $L=K(S)$ then $F(S)$ is the smallest field containing $L$ and $F$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok,

1. $S \subset L \subset LF$ and $F \subset LF$ and so $F(S) \subset LF$
2. Conversely, $F\subset F(S)$ and $L = K(S) \subset F(S)$. Since $LF$ is the smallest field containing both $L$ and $F$, it follows that $LF \subset F(S)$

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you. :-)